# '[UInt8]' or NSData/NSMutableData in Swift?

Tags: swift, arrays, nsdata, nsmutabledata

Simple question: What should we prefer if we have to deal with raw bytes in Swift: `[UInt8]` or [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/) and [NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/index.html), respectively?

What are the advantages/disadvantages using one over the other?

Comment: That depends on your requirements.

Comment: In which cases would you use `NS(Mutable)Data`, when `[UInt8]`?

Comment: Consider that Arrays in Swift are value types, meaning that their content gets copied every time if you're not explicitly passing it around by using `UnsafePointer` or `UnsafeMutablePointer`. Whereas `NSData` is a reference type which by messages like  `+ dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:` offers "built-in" control of when its payload should get copied and when not.

Comment: With raw data UInt8, we can do bitwise operation for math calculs.